# Using getX in Flutter with a singleton service

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

Using [getX](https://pub.dev/packages/get) in Flutter, suppose I need to use the same service for different controllers.

For example, the same DB service for both UsersController and ProductsController.

What would be a best practice to do that?

- Creating a singleton DB service?
- Using getIt with the DB service?
- Some other getX trick?
- GetxService?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be more accurate to create and use a singleton object with the following method.

```
Get.put<LoginService>(LoginService(), permanent: true);

Get.find<LoginService>();
```

GetX Documentation about `Get.put`

> the class that you want to get to save, like a controller or anything
>
> // note: "S" means that it can be a class of any type

Comment: but that's for the controller, not the service it calls. isn't it?

Comment: @user6097845 You can use any class you want. It doesn't have to be a controller. I added description quote from getx documentation.